# How to cut Hardie Board(Fiber Cement) Side Panelling?

Tags: patio, noise, cutting

I bought a place that has no screen patio door and I would like to install. I thought it would be quick job but I ran into a problem, there is some siding above the door that goes too far down(about a inch) and blocks me from inserting the screen.

I first thought this was wood and bought for my drill bit, HSS Saw Blades Circular Cutting. After trying to cut this "wood", I realized that this is not wood as I should have been cut it off by now.

I went to my local hardware store and they said it could be Hardie board.

How the heck do I cut this stuff? I can't take the paneling off as I don't know how and I am scared it will be hard to get it installed again, so I have to remove while installed.

How can I do this, my tools are limited. I been googling and see that some people score it and then bend it? or take a hammer to it?

[image]

Comment: Do not take a hammer to it unless someone expert tells you you can do it. It is *possible* you could make the short cuts with a hacksaw type hand saw, maybe just a hacksaw blade grasped with a heavy glove or a rag, then score the long cut repeatedly (maybe 20 times or more) and bend it out to snap it. Note, however, that the recommendation is to bend it **away from** the scoring rather than away. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D194cbqenUg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzCa2Jt1z5E

Comment: So what I meant is that if you could cut this piece by scoring and bending, then you would have to bend **toward** the scoring and this might not work at all. If I had to do it, I would try a "Dremel Saw-Max" type small circular saw (not sure what blade type). This is a fairly inexpensive tool and much easier and safer to use than a full sized circular saw (7 1/2"). This will create a lot of dust so have good breathing protection.

Comment: If the cut you make will be covered by trim, then it will not be as important to make a neat cut.

Comment: Important to note how dangerous the dust is... use high quality dust protection. If this was my job, I'd use a tile blade in a handheld grinder, but not sure if you have that at your disposal.

Comment: Basically the biggest tool I have is a drill bit. I was looking at the Dremel Saw but it is over $100 for the cheapest model and I know I probably going to use it once and maybe not use it for the next 10 years. Plus if I will need mask on top of it, not sure how much that costs as well. I could not find anywhere to rent this tool I looking for low tool solution otherwise I might  hire someone to do it.

Comment: Maybe scoring might work as there is a gap of course between the window and this paneling so I could stand inside my place and grab it and maybe it will snap.